# Create SUM of field values from 2 Tables but choose most recent date (from either table)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables with the same types of columns: `host`, `frequency`, and `date`.

The `host` is the primary key.

I want it so that I can combine a table from say March with April and sum up their frequencies.

Here is what I should expect in my final output.

- Let X be some primary key value `host`.
- If X only exists in one table, use that row in the final result.
- If X exists in both tables. Sum up both row's `freq` and select the most recent `date`. So if we had to compare between 4/20/19 vs 4/2/19, then 4/20/19 should be the date selected.

### Suppose I had the following tables:

- #### Table: Report_4.1.19

```
host    freq    date
A       15      4/1/2019
C       30      4/1/2019
```

- #### Table: Report_3.1.19

```
host    freq    date
A       10      3/1/2019
B       20      3/1/2019
```

### My ideal output should be the following:

- #### Table: Result

```
host    sum(freq)   date
A       25          4/1/2019
B       20          3/1/2019
C       30          4/1/2019
```

### Here's what I tried so far:

```
SELECT host,sum(freq),date
from
(
   select
        host,
        freq,
        date
    from Report_4.1.19
    union 
    select
        host,
        freq,
        date
    from Report_3.1.19

)
group by host
```

While my code does appear to achieve the intended result, I'm not sure if I've properly accounted for the date selection. What can I do to modify my code (if needed)?

Comment: instead of date, you could put max(date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one: use a date format supported by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), as those can be meaningfully ordered and compared, unlike what you have. `YYYY-MM-DD` works.

Step two: use one table for all reports (you already track the date as a column to tell them apart!) to keep things simple and play to the strengths of relational databases. Make the PK `host, date` instead of just `host`.

Step three: it then becomes a simple query:

```
SELECT host, sum(freq), max(date) AS date
FROM reports
GROUP BY host
ORDER BY host;
```

Comment: Hm.. now that you mention it, there's no point in me creating separate tables after all :) You're right I can just add it to a core table and query it from there!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct. Just use the max of the date column from your union.

```
SELECT host,sum(freq),max(date)
from
(
   select
        host,
        freq,
        date
    from Report_4.1.19
    union 
    select
        host,
        freq,
        date
    from Report_3.1.19

)
group by host
```

Note: If you wanted daily sums, you would use date directly and then add date to your group by clause.